# Botones con android y LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

Buenas, he creado un pequeño boton en android, con libGDX muy sencillo, pero el problema es el siguiente:

Le tengo asignada una funcion que escribe por pantalla `("hola")` algo asi:

```
if(boton.sePulsa()){
   System.out.println("hola")
  }
```

y claro pues me imprime por pantalla 3 veces o mas, `"hola"`, y yo quiero que hasta que no se vuelva a pulsar no imprima nada. Alguna ayuda pls.

//Edito la función `sePulsa()` es la siguiente:

```
public boolean sePulsaElBoton() {
    return Gdx.input.isTouched() && Gdx.input.getX() >= xMinima && Gdx.input.getX() <= xMaxima &&
            Gdx.input.getY() >= yMinima && Gdx.input.getY() <= yMaxima;
}
```

`xMaxima,Xminima`, `Yminima ,YMaxima` son de tipo `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción más común es implementar [InputProcessor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) y médiante el método **[TouchDown()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#touchDown-int-int-int-int-)** podrías detectar cuando la pantalla o tu caso, un botón es presionado.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {

...

   @Override
   public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
      return false;
   }

...

}
```

En el caso de tu implementación podrías usar simplemente:

```
public boolean sePulsaElBoton() {
    return Gdx.input.isTouched();
}
```

o  **[JustTouched](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched%28%29)** :

```
public boolean sePulsaElBoton() {
    return Gdx.input.justTouched();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa `Gdx.input.justTouched();`

`Gdx.input.isTouched()` notifica si has tocado o estas tocando la pantalla, así que si tardas 2 segundos pulsando el botón, imprimira por pantalla(en tu caso) tantos mensajes como pueda en ese tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta es vieja pero, si el botón es un `Actor` como lo son las clases `TextButton`,`Button`,`Table`,`Image` y otras, le puedes añadir un `EventListener` y listo

```
button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        super.clicked(event, x, y);
        System.out.println("Este botón se pulso!");
    }
});
```

**Tienes mucho más control, sin necesidad de programarlo tu mismo.**

**Puedes "Override" muchos metodos...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los mas que personalmente uso son:

- `InputListener` : lo uso cuando quiero detectar cuando se esta pulsando y cuando se deja de pulsar, pero tiene mucho más metodos para "Override".
- `ClickListener` :  lo uso cuando quiero detectar solo un
  pulsaso, igual tiene mucho más metodos para "Override"
- `ActorGestureListener` : lo uso cuando quiero detectar un "Long press"
  que es cuando alguien pulsa y deja pulsado un botón por mas de 1~
  segundo

Aqui una lista de todos los `EventListeners`:

- InputListener
- ClickListener
- ActorGestureListener
- ChangeListener
- DragListener
- DragScrollListener
- FocusListener
- TextArea.TextAreaListener
- TextField.TextFieldClickListener
- TextTooltip
- Tooltip